# Could not delete from tables, operations must use an updateable query?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

has anyone gotten these ms-access errors? what do they mean?

im connecting access with ODBC to a mysql database

Comment: what is the query you are using?

Comment: what kind of code are you writing?  you need to read this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: If id > 0 Then update_subjects id

Comment: "UPDATE Subjects SET ID = ? WHERE ID > 0" might be a translation of your comment. ID fields in Jet/ACE are often Autonumber fields, and not updatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 possibilities: 1) There is no primary key in the table you are trying to delete from, or 2) you don't have write permissions to the MDB.